# Where to find Work in SQL server spatial data

Tags: sql-server, gis, spatial

Where can I find previous work/sample in SQL server spatial data? The purpose is to learn how the author has created its work. Today, I'm using SQL server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example walk-through: [Using Spatial Data with SQL Server 2012, Entity Framework 5 and ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/446609/Using-Spatial-Data-with-SQL-Server-2012-Entity-Fra)

Here's an entire book you could buy on the subject: [Pro Spatial with SQL Server 2012](http://www.apress.com/9781430234913)